# Content Field Type For Video, Images and Text

Tags: entities, nodes, files

I'm trying to decide what the best method would be for creating a new Content Type who's field type would allow me the flexibility to use ANY type of content inside of it. Almost like a blank HTML container. I'd like the flexibility to manipulate the content in that space to a video, rotating image, static image or text based on my needs. Would there be an appropriate field type to manage all of this?

Or would the appropriate answer be to create three separate content types that live one after the other in the area that I want them to be, then have them hide if no content is visible in them?

Apologies if this question has been answered in the community to date, but I've yet to come across a straight answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find the Media module very flexible. With fieldable file entities everything you mention is possible as you can add long text fields to any file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best result for me actually came from creating a new field type similar to my body tag and altering information inside of it using the html view. Worked exactly as I needed it. The Conditional Fields option was far more than I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution is to use [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.
You can manage dependencies between fields.
 So you should have one field **type** and all type fields separately and display them depend to **type** field.

Comment: Thanks for the share Geg. Definitely an interesting tool, however, I don't think this is capable of doing exactly what I'm describing above. This seems like it is more or less still managing an image or a url link. Not managing multiple options in one container. Maybe I'm misunderstanding this modules possibilities?

Comment: This module can also manage multiple dependencies for fields, so I think that it's what you need. Before install this module you can also test this module on **[simplytest](http://simplytest.me/)**